# Как правильно прочитать файл в node.js

Tags: node.js

```
var path=require("path");
var url=require("url");
var fs=require("fs");
require("http").createServer(function(req, res) {    
var path_name=url.parse(req.url).pathname,
    ext=path.extname(path_name),
    file_name;
var dir_name=__dirname+"/public";
//file_name=dir_name+path_name;


fs.readdir(dir_name,function(err,folders){
    if(err){
        console.log("can not dir folder");
    }
    //console.log(typeof folders);-->object

    folders.forEach(function(folder,index){
        file_name=path.join(dir_name+"/"+folder);
        console.log(typeof file_name+" :"+file_name);

        fs.readFile(file_name+"/index.html","utf8",function(err, data) {
            if(err){
                console.log("can not read file");
            }
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    "Content-type": "text/html"
                });
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
        });
    });
});
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-type": "text/html"
});
res.write("hello");
res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

По гуглил нашел что можно переменную можно преобразовать в строку

```
var st=new String(file_name);
st.toString();
```

то же не помогло. Постоянно выскакивает ошибка
first argument must be string or Buffer

структура папки:

```
content/  
    css/  
        style.css  
    icons/  
    switch/  
          index.html
```

Comment: `res.write(data.toString());` — должно работать, что-то вы делаете не так.

Comment: ошибка cannot call method toString() of undefined

Comment: Ну ежели `data` -- undefined, так как она может быть string или Buffer?

Comment: я вас не пойму

Comment: @little_boy

    ошибка cannot call method toString() of undefined

значит объект, метод toString() которого Вы хотите вызвать -- undefined.

Comment: У вас в коде ошибка, из-за которой `data` может быть `undefined` (что вы и получили). После `console.log("can not read file");` должен быть `return`.

Answer (score 3):

Ну во-первых ваша проблема в том, что невнимательно читаете документацию.
    file_name=path.join(dir_name+"/"+folder);

Это неверно, оно список объединяет, используя разделитель о котором знает само.

Во-вторых - вы уверены насчет структуры проекта? Судя по коду у вас должно быть:

```
- app.js (приведенный выше скрипт)
- /public (директория, про которую говорится в начале)
  - /fooZZ (поддиректорИИ, которые находит fs.readdir )
    - index.html (файл, который лежит в каждой такой поддиректории)
```

Ну и еще вы в начале зачем-то парсите что-то из строки запроса и потом это выкидываете.

Самый простой вариант - посмотрите что вам дает __dirname, сопоставьте с положением вашего файла и пропишите полный путь до него. Если файл будет найден - он прочтется и будет отправлен, указывая кодировку вы намекаете fs.readFile на то чтобы вернулась строка, ничего toSting()-ить не нужно.
Причем для начала советую написать маленький отдельный пример с чтением файла, а уж потом оборачивать его в http-сервер.

Кстати, рекомендую посмотреть на фреймверк express - он несколько упрощает создание сервера и раздачу статики.